# How to wait for an async function in javascript at top level?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I know this is a terrible idea. But I have an API which I can't use until I have a piece of data which I can only get asynchronously. Something like this:

```
const key = await get_async_data(config) // NOT RIGHT, can't use await at top level
const api = new API(key)
... use api ...
```

This is at top level, outside of any function, so I can't just await get_async_data() (it does return a Promise).
Is there anything short of putting all my code in a giant async function so I can call await?

`API` is just a class exported by a module (which I control).

(BTW I thought of putting the code to get the key into the `API` class's constructor, but of course constructors can't be async either.)

I could make every async method of `API` set the key if unset, but that's pretty invasive and error-prone.

So I'm not really asking how to make my top-level code wait as much as I'm looking for alternative ways to structure this so the async call happens cleanly.

Here's some more detail in case this helps.
In api.js:

```
class API {
  constructor(key) {
    this.key = key
    // other stuff
  }
  async f1(a) {
  }
  async f2(b, c) {
  }
  f3() {
    return true
  }
}
export default API
```

Then in the places (many) where it'll be used:

```
import API from '@/api'

const key = async get_key() // NOPE
const theAPI = new API(key)

async importantMethod(args)
{
  return await theAPI.f1(args)
}
async otherMethod()
{
  if (theAPI.f3)
    return await theAPI.f2(123)
  // etc...
}
// ... and so on
```

Comment: Can you explain the issue you have with wrapping the code in an `async` function (or just using `.then`)? It would seem to be the obvious solution

Comment: I want to use this API everywhere, in all my classes. I can't wrap everything in a giant async function.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you'd need to await for this function everywhere you need to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing. Or if you dont want to wrap everything in an async function just do use .then instead.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example with more code, so we can see what looks too messy to you? It's not all that clear ATM

Comment: Just call the api, stuff the resulting promise in a var, and await as needed.

Comment: @JaredSmith with the additional detail I added, can you explain how that would work in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Promise:

```
const pendingAPI = get_async_data(config).then(key => new API(key)); // N.B. no await
export default pendingAPI;
```

Meanwhile, in another file...

```
import pendingAPI from 'other/file';
pendingAPI.then(doStuffWithAPI);
```

There are times when `async/await` is a win. But never forget it's just sugar over Promises.

Answer (score 0):

top level is a terrible idea, yes. But I don't see why you can't just put it in a function?

```
const getAsync = async () => {
  const key = await get_async_data(config);
  return key;
}
getAsync().then(key => {
  const api = new API(key)
}
```

Comment: No need for `await` / `async` if you're using `.then`, just do `get_async_data(config).then(key =>`

Comment: Also, it's not so much a "terrible idea" (it's not a bad idea, there's currently a proposal for top-level `await`) as an idea that's not currently permitted by the spec.

Comment: sure, but he seems to want a smaller function available to use elsewhere. Maybe to involve other parameters? and whether it's just pure promise or written as async await is neither here nor there.

Comment: re proposal, I didn't know that, interesting. I would still say that doing any functionality in global is generally to be avoided but I understand there are other POVs on that. I guess top level await would make it feel a bit more PHP / Python-y.

Comment: Top level in a project doesn't necessarily mean global, luckily - that's what module bundlers are for.

Comment: true, but still seems like an unnecessarily obtuse way of going about things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter your existing code as little as possible, I'd consider changing the entry point to a module which gets the key, and then calls the module which instantiates the API (the old entry point). For example:

```
// start.js
import makeApi from './makeApi';
get_key()
  .then(makeApi);

// makeApi.js
export default function(key) {
  const theApi = new API(key);
  function importantMethod(args) {
    return theAPI.f1(args)
  }
  function otherMethod() {
    if (theAPI.f3)
      return theAPI.f2(123)
  }
  // etc
}
```

In short, all you have to do is wrap your current entry point in a function.